# Ruby Method Double Splat vs Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When dealing with a method that takes a **known** number of arguments plus an options hash, is there any difference/advantage of capturing the options in a double splat?

consider

```
def method_a(a, **options)
    puts a
    puts options
end
```

vs

```
def method_b(a, options = {})
   puts a
   puts options
end
```

Are the two equivalent? I think method_b is more readable but still I see a lot of code going with method_a.
Is there a reason to use double splat for options **when the regular (non options) arguments are captured without a splat**?

Comment: Welp, they're not identical: in YARV, `method_b` has two extra instructions.

Comment: @Amadan that's fine, but how does it matter to the people reading and writing the code? to me method_a makes no sense actually but I see this pattern a lot

Comment: The latter can be called with non-hash / non-keyword arguments, e.g. `method_b(1, 2)` whereas the former ensures `options` to be a hash.

Comment: @Stefan I actually like your answer best :)

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends what you mean by "known number of arguments", specifically for the situation when you have *keyword arguments* plus *any number of other keyword args*, for example:

```
def foo(i, keyword_1: "default", **other_keywords)
end
```

I can call this as

```
foo(6, keyword_1: "asd", other: "keyword")
```

And `{other: "keyword"}` will be contained in `other_keywords` while `keyword_1` can be accessed directly as a local variable.

Without the `**` splat operator this behavior is more cumbersome to implement, something like this:

```
def foo(i, opts={})
 keyword_1 = opts.delete(:keyword_1) || "default"
 # now `opts` is the same as `other_keywords`
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't `opts.delete[:keyword_1]` be `opts.delete(:keyword_1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is the fact that the `**` version captures rest keyword arguments. Keyword arguments are represented by symbols, resulting in the following behaviour:

```
def a(**options)
  options
end

def b(options = {})
  options
end
```

```
a(a: 1) #=> {:a=>1}
a('a' => 1) #=> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))

b(a: 1) #=> {:a=>1}
b('a' => 1) #=> {"a"=>1}
```

```
def c(hash_options = {}, **keyword_options)
  [hash_options, keyword_options]
end
```

```
# symbols are extracted and used as rest keyword arguments
c('a' => 1, b: 2, 'c' => 3, d: 4) #=> [{"a"=>1, "c"=>3}, {:b=>2, :d=>4}]
```